# Parsing HTML page with PHP code in Python

Tags: python, parsing

What will be the simpler ways in Python to parse HTML page with PHP code and still get said code during parsing?

From what I've read HTML parsers in Python don't like included PHP code, so for now only option I see is to write parser myself.

On topic, Why I need this? (if someone interested): I need to convert HTML + PHP page into PHP code, which will generate JSON using command line arguments.

Comment: What does "Python to parse HTML page with PHP code" mean?

Comment: "HTML parsers in Python don't like included PHP code" is self-explanatory. PHP and Python are two different languages and using one in the other is not as simple as just pasting in code.

Comment: @tadman, I don't need to execute or even parse PHP itself, but I need HTML parser capable of extracting it. On topic "what I mean", see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Oh, you mean you need a "PHP aware HTML parser for Python".

Comment: @tadman, probably yes.